# Execute Linux command using python script to machine connected to IBM Watson Iot

Tags: python, shell, iot

Before I have tried executing commands[like ls,reboot] via Node-Red service running in localhost in raspberry pie device,and It was success. here is the node diagram.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrJTa.png) the device is connected to IBM Watson Iot cloud and it sends CPU Temperature to IBM cloud and displays temperature in a graph and at the same time It executes command too.

Now I have created a python script which connects the machine to IBM IOT server. And the script works fine, the machine is connected to IBM IOT Services . Now I want to implement Linux commands[like reboot,shutdown,ls,etc] to execute on the connected machines through another computer by using another python script via IBM IOT service data like org id,device ID,auth-token,etc! is it possible? if yes, how should I proceed with?

[NOTE: the connected machine doesn't have static ip address,and I don't want to execute command from localhost]

[code of first python script to keep the system alive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCMCs.png)

[output of first python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVKPQ.png)

Comment: are you connected via MQTT to server? @Yashwant

Comment: no.                                                                                                                                 I am not familiar with mqtt